# Sections TableView missing argument for parameter

Tags: ios, uitableview

Hey guys so I'm trying to add `Sections` to a `TableView` and running into an error called missing argument for parameter. I'm new to iOS development so my code might be not the best.

What I'm trying to do is creating three different sections and each of those sections will have an array of workouts with the same type. ie) the `mixedSection` will have workouts with type Mixed. So I'm then running through an array of Routine objects and checking the type of those and just appending it to the correct section. Then I'm going put those sections into one array which is where I run into the problem.

```
      var routines :[Routine] = routineData; 
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            var mixedSection = routineSectionData(sectionNameX: "Mixed", routineInSectionX: [Routine]());
            var strengthSection = routineSectionData(sectionNameX: "Strength", routineInSectionX: [Routine]());
            var hypertrophySection = routineSectionData(sectionNameX: "Hypertrophy", routineInSectionX: [Routine]());

            for Routine in routineData {
                if (Routine.typeOfRoutine == "Mixed") {
                    mixedSection.routineInSection.append(Routine);
                }
                else if (Routine.typeOfRoutine == "Strength") {
                    strengthSection.routineInSection.append(Routine);
                }
                else {
                    hypertrophySection.routineInSection.append(Routine);
                }
            }



  let routineSectionDataInfo = [routineSectionData(mixedSection), routineSectionData(strengthSection), routineSectionData(hypertrophySection)];
        }
```

I am getting a Missing argument for parameter `routineSectionX` in call. `routineSectionX` is I think when I `init` the `routineSectionData` I just used that name.

Answer (score 0):

The error message you are getting means, that you are not correctly fulfilling your [`Initialization` parameters.](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-ID207)

If I have a class:

```
class Person {
  let firstName: String
  let lastName: String

  init(firstName: String, lastName: String) {
    self.firstName = name
    self.lastName = lastName
  }
}
```

And I call it like this:

```
let me = Person(firstName: "ez")
```

I get the same error message as you. Because I'm not passing a second argument. So the right way would be:

```
let me = Person(firstName: "ez", lastName: "coding")
```

So check the parameters your class expects in its initialization and fulfill them and the error should go away.

Comment: Hmm still don't get it. What would be the right way of initializing in your example?